A clarification on notation regarding sums
This might seem as a very superficial question, but I am curious about notation, if not abusive. Here is a situation. We know $0 = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} (-1)^k$. If we want to split this sum we might write
$$ \sum_{k=0}^? {n \choose 2k} = \sum_{k=0}^? {n \choose 2k + 1 } $$
Now, certainly the upper bound of the sums cannot be $n$. I feel as in this situation we can just write
$$ \sum_{k \leq n } {n \choose 2k} = \sum_{k\leq n} {n \choose 2k + 1 } $$
My question is, really, is this acceptable notation in literature. If not, what is the standard notation to write such expressions.

Well, $k≤n$ on the left would give you  terms like $\binom n{2n}$, which really isn't what you want.

If $k \le n$, then $2k$ and $2k+1$ can be larger than $n$...

It looks like you want to split the sum between odd and even terms.  An "obvious" approach would be to write
$$ \sum_{\substack{k=0}\\k\text{ odd}}^{n} \binom{n}{k} = \sum_{\substack{k=0}\\k\text{ even}}^{n} \binom{n}{k}. $$

One option is to specify the full range of $2k$ or $2k+1$ and write it as $$\sum_{k\ :\ 0 \leq 2k \leq n } {n \choose 2k} = \sum_{k\ :\ 0\leq 2k+1\leq n} {n \choose 2k + 1 }.$$
Another option is to use floor function $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ and write it as $$\sum_{ k=0 }^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} {n \choose 2k} = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor} {n \choose 2k + 1 }.$$
